# Series of FileReadLine command

Tags: autohotkey

Searching in files for some code lines. My script for first line:

```
FileReadLine, OutputVar, C:\Files\prog.txt, 1
If (OutputVar = "FileRead, OutputVar, C:\Files\prog1.txt")
    MsgBox Code line found
else
    MsgBox Code line not found
```

How searching by this method in some area? Lines from 50 to 250, 205 to 551, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a file parsing loop: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/LoopReadFile.htm

```
Loop, read, C:\Files\prog.txt
{
    If (A_LoopReadLine = "FileRead, OutputVar, C:\Files\prog1.txt") {
        MsgBox, An interesting code line was found.
    } Else If (A_LoopReadLine = "blablabla") {
        MsgBox, An interesting code line was found.
    } Else If (A_LoopReadLine = "some other text line") {
        MsgBox, An interesting code line was found.
    ;} Else {
    ;    MsgBox, Nothing important was found
    ;}

}
```

Comment: It very exactly code. But how modify my code? For more other methods and purposes using.